# Error trying to add junit dependency to maven in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, dependencies, maven-3, pom.xml

I am using Intelli J as the IDE and maven(3.3.9) as my build tool. After I completed my code in Java I was trying to add junit dependency to my pom.xml but maven doesn't seem to recognize the dependency. I came across a few other related questions on this issue but on trying all possible solutions exhaustively the problem still seems to persists.

My pom.xml currently looks like:

[image]

Following are the possible fixes I tried to alleviate the issue:

1. **Downloading Library from Maven Repository from Project Structure**

Specifying the junit dependency through the Project Structure (File > Project Structure > Libraries > New Project Library (from Maven)). I searched for junit and chose junit:junit:4.11 but I get "No files were downloaded"

[image]

2. **Makes changes in the Project Setting for Maven**

I went to File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Maven and I checked Use plugin directory and changed maven to the appropriate location. It looks like follows:

[image]

Following that I also went to File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Maven > Importing and checked Import Maven Projects automatically.

[image]

3. **Running maven**

Then I also ran maven clean install which ran with success after downloading some files:

[image]

4. **Re-importing All Maven Projects**

I also re-imported all maven projects from the Maven Projects tab on the right but I end up with unresolved plugins and the an error popup saying "Failed to read artifact descriptor for junit:junit:jar:4.11" when I hover over the red-lines.

[image]

Can someone tell me anything else I might have missed if you have ever encountered the same before ?

Thanks!